# Initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue when passing opencv Mat to a function

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an Mat. I want to update the mat based on certain regions defined by a Rect. When I pass it like the code shown below I get the error mentioned.

```
void temp2(Mat &A){
  //this function updates the value of A in the region defined by the rect.
 for(i = 0 to A.rows){
  Vec2f *p = reinterpret_cast<Vec2f * >(A.ptr(i));
  for(j = 0 to A.cols){
   //  p[j] = Vec2f(5,5);
}
}
}
void temp1(Mat &A){
  Point a(0,0), b(10,10);
  Rect t(a,b);
  temp2(A(t));
}

void temp(Mat &A){
  A  = Mat(500, 500, CV_32FC2, Scalar(-1.0, -1.0));
  temp1(A);
}
int main(){
  
 Mat A;
 temp(A);

}
```

I looked up the solution and it said to make the mat A const in the temp2 function.I cant make the mat A const in the temp2 function as I have to update the specific region of the mat defined by the rect in the temp2 function. How can I update the specific region in this manner?

Comment: `temp2(A(t));` will modify a new temporary object of type `A` then the temporary object and all changes to it get thrown away at the closing `;` - this is probably now what you want to do.  Please show the definition of `Mat` and read [mcve]

Comment: `for(i = 0 to A.rows)` - I don't know where did you get this syntax from, but it's wrong.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen this a psuedocode

Comment: @RichardCritten it is cv::Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
 /* Renamed arg to reflect what's happening.
    Let it be A if you so wish but it's not
    the original A from temp(). 
  */   
void temp2(Mat &extractedFromA){
  // Do stuff
}
void temp1(Mat &A){
  Point a(0,0), b(10,10);
  Rect t(a,b);
  Mat extracted = A(t);
  temp2(extracted);
}
```

You are using [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57) API

```
Mat cv::Mat::operator() (const Rect & roi)const
```

which means that on calling `A(t)`, `A` is unmodified (since above API is a const method) and yields a ***new `Mat` object*** and this is what you need to operate on in `temp2()`, not the original object `A` passed into `temp1()`. Also the changes made to the `extracted` `Mat` shall be reflected back to the original `Mat A` since you're only sharing the headers between them.

Also, the error that you might be hitting into is that since `A(t)` was yielding a temporary object, and on passing it to `temp2()`, you were attempting to bind it to a non-const lvalue reference. Making it as a const lvalue reference would fix it but that obviously won't help you.

Comment: I have to call that temp2 function various times for different regions of the mat A. Hence returning each time is not what I am looking for. Is there some way that I can update it in the temp2 function only without returning

Comment: @user16401289 I've updated the explanation in my answer.  My earlier understanding was incorrect. You can just keep on extracting the submatrixes from `A` and then pass it to `temp2()`. The changes to the submatrix shall reflect back to `A`. You don't need to keep on returning the `extracted` `Mat`.